# Get values of array outside while loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Why am I only getting last value in this array outside while loop. Shouldn't it hold all records? Why array is not built with all the values from query?

This is my code.

```
$cost_array = array(); 
if ($stmt = $conn_mysqli -> prepare("SELECT costs_items.cno, costs_items.name,costs_items.description, costs_items.type,costs_items.measure, costs_items.amount, costs_items.vc_fc,costs_items_custom.cno, costs_items_custom.name, costs_items_custom.description, costs_items_custom.type, costs_items_custom.measure, costs_items_custom.amount, costs_items_custom.vc_fc FROM costs_items LEFT JOIN costs_items_custom ON costs_items.costs_id = costs_items_custom.costs_id WHERE costs_items.costs_id = ?")) {
         $stmt -> bind_param("i", $costs_select);   
         $stmt -> execute();
         $stmt -> bind_result($cno, $cost_name, $cost_description, $cost_type, $cost_measure, $cost_amount, $cost_vcfc, $ccustom_cno, $ccustom_name, $ccustom_description, $ccustom_type, $ccustom_measure, $ccustom_amount, $ccustom_vc_fc);
         while($stmt -> fetch()){

            //Here we put all costs in array
            $cost_array['cno'] = $cno;
            $cost_array['cost_name'] = $cost_name;
            $cost_array['cost_description'] = $cost_description;
            $cost_array['cost_type'] = $cost_type;
            $cost_array['cost_measure'] = $cost_measure;
            $cost_array['cost_amount'] = $cost_amount;
            $cost_array['cost_vcfc'] = $cost_vcfc;

        }
        $stmt -> close();                                      }

    var_dump($cost_array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:use `[]` to create new index.

```
 $cost_array = array(); 
while($stmt -> fetch()){
    $cost_array['cno'][] = $cno;
    $cost_array['cost_name'][] = $cost_name;
    $cost_array['cost_description'][] = $cost_description;
    $cost_array['cost_type'][] = $cost_type;
    $cost_array['cost_measure'][] = $cost_measure;
    $cost_array['cost_amount'][] = $cost_amount;
    $cost_array['cost_vcfc'][] = $cost_vcfc;

}
$stmt -> close();          

var_dump($cost_array);//all your values
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
 $cost_array[] = array(
      'cno' => $cno,
      'cost_name' => $cost_name,
      'cost_description' => $cost_description
    );
```